# Semantic ui ribbon edge is inverted and only works correctly on the right side

Tags: semantic-ui

[image]

As you can see the small triangular edge below the ribbon is reflected - meaning the right angle should be the other side-. While it works correctly when I flip the direction - using dir="rtl" - , I can't use it on the left side.

```
<div v-if="isRunning" class="ui four wide column" >
           <div class="ui blue attached basic label ribbon" dir="ltr"> REMAINING SECONDS </div>
          <div class="ui label massive fluid ">
              {{remainingSeconds}}
            </div>
      </div>
```

Below is a demonstration of the right version of the ribbon label which works correctly.
[image]

How can I make it work correctly?

Comment: try to remove dir attribute

Comment: It wasn't there initially. Then I added it and the problem persisted.